R emmeans for outer nesting variable (unbalanced nested variables)
I have a model with a nested variable that is only meaningful within one level of another variable, i.e. the case described in this question and explanation on CrossValidated.
The reproducible example below has a continuous variable 'var' that is only meaningful for level B of factor 'fac'. All values of 0 in 'var' are meaningless and should not effect the estimate of the effect of 'var'. All values or 'var' within 'fac = A' are thus 0. Inconveniently, there are also two rows with level B where the value of 'var' is 0 (i.e., missing data). To let these rows still contribute to the overall estimate for the effect of B, I have created another factor name 'var.spec' indicating whether a value of var is specified (yes or no).
I would really like to get an emmean for each level of fac (A and B), averaged across all values of var, but I just get 'nonEst' and 'NA' results. Is it possible to get emmeans for A and B, or is it not working because I am trying to force emmeans to do something it shouldn't?
   #example data
   df<-structure(list(fac = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                           "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                   var.spec = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
                                "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                "yes", "yes", "yes"), 
                   var = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 22L,
                           24L, 20L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 30L),
                   response = c(24L, 24L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 19L, 
                                21L, 29L, 33L, 43L, 35L, 43L, 31L, 41L, 41L, 
                                36L, 45L)), 
              class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = c(NA,-20L))

    #model
    mod<-lm(response ~ fac + fac:var.spec + fac:var.spec:var,
            data=df)
    
    #emmeans
    emmeans(mod, ~ fac)
      #NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
      #    var.spec %in% fac
      #NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
      # fac emmean SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
      # A   nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
      # B   nonEst NA NA        NA        NA
    
    Results are averaged over the levels of: var.spec 
    Confidence level used: 0.95 



                                            

